# "Two types one is [type 1] and one is [type 2]" vs "Two types one is [type 1] and other is [type 2]"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

> Two types, one is [type 1] and **one** is [type 2]

OR

> Two types, one is [type 1] and **other** is [type 2]

To me the second one sounds correct but I am not sure about the first one.

Example :

1. There are two types of relationships. One is needs based and other is love based.
2. There are two types of caches. One is Write-through cache and one is Write-back cache.

Comment: Neither of these is a complete sentence, so it's hard to say what is correct or not.  Can you give us an entire sentence that you want to use these in?

Comment: @stangdon Example : 1) There are two types of relationships. One is needs based and other is love based. 2) There are two types of caches. One is Write-through cache and one is Write-back cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use *the* with *other*:

> There are two types of **relationship**. One is needs-based and **the other** is love-based.

This is perfectly fine:

> There are two types of relationship. One is needs-based and one is love-based.

You don't actually need either structure.
There is an old joke which goes:

> There are 10 kinds of people in the word: those who understand binary and those who don't.

(I chose to hypenate "needs-based" but this is a personal style choice.)